# Store Decimal values without Trailing Zeros

Tags: sql-server-2008, datatypes

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 version.

Is there any method to store decimal value in SQL without extra trailing zeros(like Float data type format).

I have created a column with decimal data type with highest precision.

Actual values:

```
2.50000000
4.55530000
1.85333310
```

Expected:

```
2.5
4.5553
1.8533331
```

Is it possible to store  values in above expected format with highest precision ?

Comment: If you use row compression internally the data will be stored according to the size required. Are you not mixing up data presentation & storage ? A decimal datatype is defined with a fixed number of digits before and after the decimal point (precision & scale in the documentation). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You could use a view to look at your data, and format the columns up just as you like them.

Answer (score 3):

The storage of Data shouldn't concern  you, as long you have the wanted precision

and representation of the data you can do on your application.

If you want a select that will remove the trailing Zeros

you can use

```
SELECT convert(DOUBLE PRECISION, 20.10)
```